# [Wix][Custom Element] How to let trigger event after connectedCallback?

Tags: javascript, custom-element, velo

I'm using Wix to build a chat page. I'm using a custom element to display chats. Now I want to add a storage to store chat history and automatically display those history chats when user open the chat page. The problem is that when should I perform the fetch history and display action?

First, I tried to add history reader in page code and rely on attributeChangedCallback to let my custom element render the history. However it does not work, because the custom element was not even attached to DOM(connectedCallback is not called yet), when the attributeChangedCallback is triggered.

Second, I tried to add event dispatcher in connenectedCallback to trigger page code fetch chat history. It still does not work because the event dispatcher does not trigger anything.

I'm curious how can I implement this auto loading history functionality. The problem is that I can only fetch storage in page code (where I can use Velo API), and then send that history chats data to custom element to display. I have already implemented chatting functionality. User can enter their questions and click send button to trigger all the following actions in custom element. Just I cannot correctly trigger the event automatically after the page is loaded.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: maybe try firing a 'loaded' event from the custom element once it's loaded. then on your velo code, listen to this event, and only then send the data to the custom element using setAttribute()

Comment: This may help you https://youtu.be/a9gqQDByleU?t=1021